# Specify that a function accepts A and B and returns class C(A, B) with Python type hints

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider the following code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')
def combine(a: type[A], b: type[B]):
    class C(a,b):
        ...
    return C


class C1:
    def c1(self):
        return 'c1'

class C2:
    def c2(self):
        return 'c2'

print(combine(C1, C2)().c1())
print(combine(C1, C2)().c2())
```

Let's say that the philosophical aspect is covered by just prohibiting shared methods such that we never have the diamond problem.
How can I make it work with typing?

Currently, I'm not using `A` and `B` `TypeVars` because I don't know how. However, I would like the return value to be somehow dependent on those two in a way that tells the type checker that indeed `C` is a subclass of `A` and `B`. An alternative would be to be able to customise what the type checker is doing with `def __instancecheck__` or some other means.

Comment: i think its a good idea to state that i did think about explicitly inheriting before the function declaration and i did read about the attempts to create a decent intersection type that would respect the MRO [#213](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)

Comment: static type checkers don't do anything with `__instancecheck__`

Comment: If you are aware of the fact that we are missing the [`Intersection`](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) type, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg as far as i know, `Intersection` is rigorous and is mainly about protocols and mixins - i would happily hack my way through that whiteboard reasoning if only i could do inheritance

Comment: I don't know what that means. The fact of the matter is that what you are describing literally **is** the intersection of types. You want the type checker to know that after passing `A` and `B` as arguments, the function returns a type that is both `A & B` (which is what inheriting from `A` and `B` _always_ implies).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I thought that a general vague notion of an intersection is not a problem, I thought that the problem starts when you consider what to do with method duplicates, differing inits and all MRO stuff (because of course typing wouldn't release a feature that doesn't work in half of the cases). Hence, my understanding was that the problem isn't in class C(A, B) itself. But it seems I'm wrong?

Comment: The problem is that we don't have an intersection type. I feel like a broken record. You keep talking about problems to solve when trying to properly formulate, implement and type-check an intersection type, as though that is your goal. But what does this have to do with your question? How is a "vague notion of an intersection" going to help you? It does not change the fact that you want to express the intersection of two types, which is impossible because we don't have an intersection type.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg you state it like the type checker doesnt have a notion of multiple inheritance and im asking for some missing functiinality. However, the following code:
```

def f(x: Any):`\n` if not isinstance(x, C1) or not isinstance(x, C2): raise; reveal_type(x)
```
reveals that after the guard the type is `x: <subclass of C1 and C2>`. We clearly have the concept and all required machinery already